# string to byte array

Tags: c#, c++, c, delphi

I get very very long packets that are logged into a text file. But some I have to check for errors.
example(a very short one):

```
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
```

I need an application that'd insert a ',0x' inbetween every byte so that later I can declare it as a static array.

The problem is that if I add this as a string, the compiler gives errors, because the string is too long. For this reason I'd be good if you could help me do this in one of the languages: C/C++,C# or Delphi.

Comment: What language are you using currently?  Also, please post code if you have errors.  I'm guessing you're using a data type that is immutable and so trying to resize it won't work.  You might have to allocate a new array and add the "0x" as you move your packet to the new array.\

Comment: How about a text editor? Find `([0-9]{8})`, replace by `0x\1 `.

Comment: What do you mean the string is too long? How long are your strings in general?

Answer (score 5):

You can use C# to convert your string to a byte array by using:

```
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourString);
```

Answer (score 2):

C#:

```
// get entire string
var contents = File.ReadAllText("filename.txt");
// convert every 2 digits 'AA' into ',0xAA'
contents = Regex.Replace(contents, "..", ",0x$0").Trim(',');
// output to another file
File.WriteAllText("filename2.txt");
```

Comment: +1 because doing it with the Replace of Regex... Priceless :-)

Comment: It's the easiest way, I'm pretty sure OP is not asking for UTF8.GetBytes -- the original file is already in byte-values. He's trying to get it into a format he can copy into a code file.

Answer (score 0):

In C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        if (isprint(ch)) {
            if (! isspace(ch)) {
                printf("0x%c", ch);
            } else {
                printf("[0x%X]", ch);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To invoke:

Windows:

```
type filename | program.exe
```

Unix:

```
cat filename | ./program
```

There is a distinction for spaces, tabs, newlines and carriage returns because you will inevitably encounter them in your efforts.